# how to store and access a value in session in web api controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Hello every one I am making a web API application in which i want use OTP verification at register time and i want store this value in session and after after that i want match it with otp code enter by user so how can i achieve this.

My controller code is given bellow

```
  public class EmailSetupController : ApiController
        {
            public string ToAddress { get; private set; }

            [HttpPost]
            [Route("api/EmailSetup/SendEmail/{ToEmail}")]
            public IHttpActionResult InsertUserAltAddRegTime([FromUri]string ToEmail)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }

     int otp = new Random().Next(100000, 999999);
      session["CurrentOtp"] = otp;
    // Rest code for sending otp via email and it's working well
        :
        :

    return Ok();

            }



    }
```

I want store it in a session and match with enter by user otp in jquery ajax please help me

Comment: In general webAPI is intended for stateless operation.  If you have a session ID stored somewhere on your server you probably need to contrive a way to pass its value back and forth on each call. In your processing you will most likely need to retrieve, validate, update, re-store your session state.  This is far more complicated when you have multiple physical machines behind your web service that just your single dev box.

Comment: thanks for comment but i solve it by other way

Comment: consider sharing your solution for others.

Comment: I use database and stored procedure for storing otp and checking it and removing also it